# When is grails filter order calculated when using dependsOn

Tags: grails, filter

I've read the [official documentation on filter dependencies](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#6.6.4%20Filter%20Dependencies), but I cannot find any information about how the ordering is calculated (for different filter classes). Is it at runtime or during the build process?

I know that with Plugins we can participate in building `web.xml` and there we can make sure we come after a certain filter.

Does `dependsOn` also work by adding the filters to the `web.xml` file?

Comment: The filters defined in `grails-app/conf` are not the same as Servlet filters which are defined in `web.xml`. These are two different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filters defined in `grails-app/conf` are not the same as Servlet filters which are defined in `web.xml`. These are two different things.

The order of Grails filters is determined when the application starts up.

Comment: What I am concerned about is extra processing due to ordering when I hit the filters. I suppose you're saying there's no problem there. Could you also point me to where this is documented? I cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/bcb843a03b67f8d51920eaef847efd976babdc4d/grails-plugin-filters/src/main/groovy/org/grails/plugins/web/filters/FiltersGrailsPlugin.groovy you will see that the filters are setup in dependency/sorted order, so it is only evaluated once.